# swift optional array subscripts

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

Simple playground code like below:

```
var array :[Int?]
array = [1, 2, 3]
array![1] = 4
```

Got an error from Playground

> Playground execution failed: error: :8:1: error: '@lvalue $T6' is not identical to 'Int?'
>   array![1] = 4

Any suggestion guy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the answer by myself

```
var array :[Int]?
array = [1, 2, 3]
if var tmpArray = array {
    tmpArray[1] = 4
    array = tmpArray
}
```

How could I say this, Cons&Pros

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a non-optional array of optional Ints. When you try to access it you are trying to force unwrap the array itself which is not necessary. You can simply do:

```
array[1] = 4
```

An optional array of non-optional Int would look like this:

```
var array: [Int]?
```

Comment: We all see where this is headed...might as well throw this here:https://devforums.apple.com/message/998882#998882

Comment: When I define a optional array like below

    var array :[Int]?
    array = [1, 2, 3]
    array![1] = 4

I got this

>Playground execution failed: error: <EXPR>:8:1: error: '@lvalue $T6' is not identical to 'Int'
array![1] = 4